# How to extract text from a string, given the first and last word in text

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following text in a cell.

> I am using stackoverflow.
> Stackoverflow is a question and answer forum.
> Let’s say I have one more line.

I have split this into an array.

```
Arr[0] = I am using stackoverflow.   
Arr[1] = Stackoverflow is a question and answer forum.   
Arr[2] = Let’s say I have one more line.
```

How can I retrieve the text from `Arr[1]` from `answer` till `forum`.

> Output should be - `answer forum`

Comment: `Mid(Arr(1), Instr(Arr(1), "answer"), 12)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you don't know exactly where in your `Arr(1)` that the word "answer" occurs, and that the word "forum" does not occur directly after it, i.e. that the variable `Arr(1)` **might** contain the string `"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site and is not a forum like so many other sites"`. (Which is actually a better description of Stack Overflow!)

```
Dim temp As String
Dim result As String
arr(1) = "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site and is not a forum like so many other sites"

'Get everything after the first occurrence of "answer"
temp = Mid(arr(1), InStr(arr(1), "answer"))

'Get everything before the first occurrence of "forum"
result = Left(temp, InStr(temp, "forum") + 4)  ' + 4 because the InStr will point to the "f" of "forum"

'result will contain "answer site and is not a forum"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use substring.

```
Dim substring As String = RIGHT(arr[1], 13)
```

where 13 can be replaced with the length of the substring. Make sure the length isn't going to cause an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: VBA question, not VB.Net.  (VBA doesn't allow initialisation of the variable in the declaration statement.)  (And I don't think VBA **or** VB.Net allow `[]` instead of `()`)

Comment: And VBA doesn't give an OOB - e.g. `right("abc",10)` will just return `"abc"`.

Comment: @ThomasCook: Definitely **not** VBA.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most robust answer depending on what your use case is. But the `right()` function will work.

```
answerString = Right(Arr(1), 13)
'answer forum.
```

Comment: It's morning in Europe ;-)

Comment: Don't know - I can.

Comment: @YowE3K Ahh you're right. I copied straight from the original post. But yes, should be `( )`. I have edited my answer to reflect.